# Me podrían ayudar por favor

Tags: java

```
/*
```

No me den dislike porfa apenas empiezo en esto; exactamente hace 3 semanas y sin ayuda. :)

`Bueno lo que desearía hacer es que cada vez que un resultado negativo me repita lo pedido en un bucle while`

`Salida:`

`Como desea ingresar al sistema como profesor o estudiante
Profesor > pasa al siguiente metodo
    ^
Resultado positivo > Ingrese usuario y contraseña\nUsuario: y así sucesivamente. >>>OJO<<<
El código aún no lo termino así que no se concentren en las otras partes.`

`waduaidwa > Por favor, ingrese los datos correctamente
    ^
Resultado negativo`

`"" > Debe completar el espacio para acceder al sistema
 ^
Resultado negativo
*/`

Vale aquí empieza el código

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Program {`

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("Como desea ingresar al sistema como profesor o estudiante");

        String opt = sc.nextLine();  //variable called option

        if (!opt.equals("Profesor") || !opt.equals("profesor") || !opt.equals("Estudiante") || !opt.equals("estudiante")) {

        System.out.println ("Por favor, ingrese los datos correctamente") ;

        opt = sc.nextLine();

        while (!opt.equals("Profesor") || !opt.equals("profesor") || !opt.equals("Estudiante") || !opt.equals("estudiante")) {

        System.out.println ("Por favor, ingrese los datos correctamente");

        opt = sc.nextLine();

        }

        } else if (opt.equals("")) {

        System.out.println ("Debe completar el espacio para acceder al sistema");

        while (opt.equals("")) {

        System.out.println ("Debe completar el espacio para acceder al sistema");

        opt = sc.nextLine();

        }

        } else if (opt.equals("Profesor") || opt.equals("profesor")) {

        Prof1 ();

        } else if (opt.equals("Estudiante") || opt.equals("estudiante")) {

        Stud1 ();

      }
    }


        static void Prof1 () {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("\nIngrese usuario y contraseña\nUsuario:");

        String Usr = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Contraseña:");

        String Pwd = sc.nextLine();

        if (Usr.equals("") && Pwd.equals("") ) {

        System.out.println ("\nSe solicita usuario y contraseña\nUsuario");

        Usr = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Contraseña");

        Pwd = sc.nextLine();

        while (Usr.equals("") && Pwd.equals("") ) {

        System.out.println ("Se solicita usuario y contraseña\nUsuario");

        Usr = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Contraseña");

        Pwd = sc.nextLine();

        }


        } else if (Usr.equals("") ) {

        System.out.println("\nSe solicita usuario\nUsuario");

        Usr = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Contraseña");

        Pwd = sc.nextLine();

        while (Usr.equals("") ) {

        System.out.println("Se solicita usuario\nUsuario");

        Usr = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Contraseña");

        Pwd = sc.nextLine();

        }


        } else if (Pwd.equals("") ) {

        System.out.println("\nSe solicita contraseña\nUsuario");

        Usr = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Contraseña");

        Pwd = sc.nextLine();

        while (Usr.equals("") ) {

        System.out.println("Se solicita contraseña\nUsuario");

        Usr = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Contraseña");

        Pwd = sc.nextLine();

        }


        if (Usr.equals("Nelson") && Pwd.equals("v1d4nu3v4") ) {

        System.out.println("\nBienvenido de nuevo");

        Prof2 ();

        }else{

        System.out.println("\nUsario o contraseña incorrectos");

    }
}

    static void Prof2 () {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("De que estudiante desea ingresar las notas?");

        String s11 = sc.nextLine();

        if (s11.equals ("")) {

        System.out.println ("Por favor, ingrese lo solicitado");

        } else if (s11.equals ("Steven")) {

        Prof3 ();

        } else {

        System.out.println ("Estudiante no encontrado en el sistema\n¿Desea agregarlo?\n<Función no disponible de momento>");

        }
    }

    static void Prof3 () {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("Ingrese las notas del estudiante\nMatemática:");

        double Pe = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("Física:");

        double Mth = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("Deporte:");

        double Sc = sc.nextDouble();

        String nom [] = {"Educación física ", "Matemática ","Science "};

        double promedio = (Pe + Mth + Sc)/nom.length;

        if (promedio >= 10){

        System.out.println ("Ha ingresado los datos incorrectamente; recuerde que las notas nunca son mayores a 10");

        } else {

        System.out.println ("-------------------------------------" + "\nPromedio de Steven: " + promedio + "\n" + nom[0] + Pe + "\n" + nom[1] + Mth + "\n" + nom[2] + Sc );

      }
    }


    static void Stud1 () {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("Ingrese usuario y contraseña\nUsuario:");

        String Usr = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Contraseña:");

        String Pwd = sc.nextLine();

        if (Usr.equals("") && Pwd.equals("") ) {

        System.out.println ("\nSe solicita usuario y contraseña");

        } else if (Usr.equals("") ) {

        System.out.println("\nSe solicita usuario");

        } else if (Usr.equals("Steven") && Pwd.equals("Doggo") ) {

        System.out.println("\nBienvenido de nuevo\nRevise sus notas");

        // Stud2 ();

        }else{

        System.out.println("\nUsario o contraseña incorrectos");


    }
    }

}
```

//final de la clase

https://code.sololearn.com/cSNVLlrF4Qx7/#java

Comment: Para empezar te puedo recomendar la indentacion.  Es muy dificil leer tu codigo si no separas los diferentes bloques con la indentacion necesaria.  Ademas, no necesitas una linea en blanco para separar cada linea.  Generalmente, las lineas en blanco se utilizan para separar diferentes bloques en tu codigo.

Comment: ok, pero puedes responder mi pregunta porfa ya voy a aprender eso

Comment: Cual es el problema con tu codigo?

Comment: Ahí está explicado al inicio

Comment: Se lo que quieres hacer.  Tambien veo algunos ciclos while en tu codigo.  Mi pregunta es, que es lo que no te funciona en tu codigo?

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta en base a [ask] ,de esta forma obtendrás buenas respuestas @Steve.

Comment: ok te resumo todo lo que intente
Primer intento > fail en cuanto al funcionamiento que deseaba > sin errores de compilación
todo funciona guay pero el problema es que si le doy a espacio primero me va a aparecer el error de mala digitacion. "Por favor, ingrese los datos correctamente"

Comment: te dejo un link para que la lectura se te haga más fácil

Comment: https://code.sololearn.com/cRccw92Jtu3M/#java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

creo que he captado lo que quieres hacer, he escrito este codigo que se comportaria como quieres, dime si hay algo que no entiendes.

```
public class profeoalumn{
//Preguntar si es profesor o alumno
public static String prof_alumn(String user_type, Scanner sc){
    System.out.println("Es usted profesor o alumno?");
    user_type = sc.nextLine();
    while(!(user_type.toLowerCase().equals("profesor")) && !(user_type.toLowerCase().equals("alumno")) ){
        System.out.println("Por favor, ingrese los datos correctamente:");
        user_type=sc.nextLine();
    }
    return user_type;
}

//Se identifica el usuario
public static boolean identificar(String user_type, Scanner sc,boolean profesor) {
    String datos_user,datos_pass;
    System.out.println("Porfavor ingrese su usuario:");
    datos_user=sc.nextLine();
    switch(user_type.toLowerCase()) {
        case "profesor": while(!(datos_user.equals(profesor_user))) {
                            System.out.println("Introduzca un usuario de profesor valido.");
                            datos_user=sc.nextLine();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Escribe la contraseña Profesor:");
                        datos_pass=sc.nextLine();
                        while(!(datos_pass.equals(profesor_pwd))) {
                            System.out.println("Introduzca una contraseña de profesor valida.");
                            datos_pass=sc.nextLine();
                        }
                        break;
        case "alumno": while(!(datos_user.equals(alu_user))) {
                            System.out.println("Introduzca un usuario de alumno valido.");
                            datos_user=sc.nextLine();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Escribe la contraseña Alumno:");
                        datos_pass=sc.nextLine();
                        while(!(datos_pass.equals(alu_pwd))) {
                            System.out.println("Introduzca una contraseña de alumno valida.");
                            datos_pass=sc.nextLine();
                        }
                        profesor=false;
                        break;
    }
    return profesor;
}
//Constantes
static String profesor_user = "profesor";
static String profesor_pwd ="profpass";
static String alu_user ="alumno";
static String alu_pwd ="alupass";
public static void main(String[] args){
    String user_type="";
    boolean profesor=true;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    user_type=prof_alumn(user_type,sc);;
    profesor=identificar(user_type,sc,profesor);
    if(profesor) {
        System.out.println("Bienvenido profesor");
    }else {System.out.println("Bienvenido alumno");}
}
```

}  En la funcion prof_alumn el bucle nos asegura que hasta que no se escriba o profesor o alumno no va a parar de preguntar, y la funcion toLowerCase() hace que tanto si escriben "Profesor" como "PROFESOR" como "profesor" sea valido, ya que transformara las mayusculas en minusculas a la hora de la comparacion.

Comment: Pos como recién inicio en esto no entiendo nada; me podrías explicar todo porfavor y ya que tu sabes tanto donde aprendiste ya se que todo va a su paso pero así me puedo orientar mejor. Ah y por cierto yo programo en el simbolo del sistema por si acaso (cmd)

Comment: Bueno me voy al parque así que de momento no podré responderte; por si acaso mi gmail es stevenmerino2015@yahoo.es

Comment: Lo primero te recomiendo que utilices un editor de texto como notepad++ para iniciarte y acostumbrarte a la sintaxi, y luego te pases a un IDE como Netbeans o Eclipse, ambos gratuitos. Respondiendo a dónde aprendí estoy estudiano Desarrollo de aplicaciones multiplataforma, y el codigo que te he escrito utiliza las estructuras mas basicas de la programacion que son condicionales: sentencias if, if else y switch y bucles: while, do while y for. Antes de intentar escribir programas con un minimo de complejidad mejor interioriza esas sentencias y haz programas simples para practicarlas

Comment: solo una cosa le ejecute en el cmd y me dió 4 errores

Comment: Los errores se deben seguramente a que falta el import java.util.Scanner; pero si no me das mas detalles no se que puede ser. El codigo lo he estado probando y funciona.

Comment: Ok, ya lo ejecuto cuando vuelva

Comment: Talvez me podrías poner el completo con todo e importación para no confundirme

Comment: Solo debes añadir como primera linea, arriba del todo lo siguiente:  import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya aprendí mas y ahora si entiendo el código; solo tengo una pregunta como te sirve la declaración de Scanner sc en el método sin tener que poner Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Y que pasa cuando le dices return user_type?

Comment: Que la variable user_type del main coje el valor de la variable user_type de la funcion.

Comment: ¿Porque pones dos veces punto y coma en esta sentencia?
user_type=prof_alumn(user_type,sc);;

Comment: También cuál es su significado prque pones , que clase de expresión es y como funciona.